# Irssi settings and Bash's Environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables, irssi

How can I define settings, such as ircname, nick and such things, in .bashrc for Irssi?

Comment: Keep in mind that *after* successfully updating this, you need to `/disconnect` and reconnect, before they'll update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings for Irssi go in `~/.irssi/config`.

However, in general, any Bash environment variable is set in `~/.bashrc` like this:

```
export varname=value
```

The real question is how do you get Irssi to use those variables?

Comment: I'd like to keep my freenode password in an environment variable or external file, so I can keep my irssi config in a public dotfiles repository. Any suggestions?

Comment: From https://github.com/irssi/irssi/blob/master/docs/special_vars.txt, it appears that env vars are made available as variables in the config

Answer (score 3):

A much better way would be to set all these settings to your `irssi` config file. For example, this command will change the nickname:

```
/set nick Heoa
```

And every time you start `irssi`, this nickname will be used.

---

If you still want it - `irssi` supports these environment variables:

- **`IRCNICK`** - `nick`
- **`IRCNAME`** - `real_name` (the `ircname` line in `/whois` output)
- **`IRCUSER`** - `user_name` (also called ident)
- **`IRCHOST`** - `hostname` (you will probably never use this one)

Note that these environment variables are only set on the first run, and they are ignored if `~/.irssi/config` exists.

Comment: I'd like to keep my freenode password in an environment variable or external file, so I can keep my irssi config in a public dotfiles repository. Any suggestions?

Comment: @rizumu: Passwords in environment variables are a stupid idea, because every program would get a copy of it without even asking. As for external file... As for external files, you can have this on Freenode - by using a [SASL authentication script](http://nullroute.eu.org/~grawity/irssi-autoidentify.html#sasl). SASL is the preferred way of authentication on IRC.

Comment: @rizumu: However, next time you have questions _not_ directly related to my answer, please [submit them](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) as a separate post, not as a comment.

Comment: @rizumu: ...also, for SASL-incapable networks, I used to have a script that would grab the server password from a file. I'll try to find it.

Comment: I now realize this should have been a separate question, but all searching led me here and it seemed related enough at the time. Well thanks for the tip.

Comment: When I type `\set real_name isomorphismes` it doesn't change the output of `\whois mynicknameonfreenode`.

Comment: @isomorphismes: This information is sent only once when connecting; it cannot be updated in the middle of connection. (Also, it is `/set` and `/whois`.)

Answer (score 1):

While I can imagine setting alias like:

```
alias irssi="irssi -c some.server -n your_nick"
```

it doesn't make sense. Irssi is very configurable, and it has a proper config file, so why don't you use it?

For example:

Start irssi, issue /network add; /server add; /channel add commands - best if you'd set the server and channel to auto-connect and autojoin.

Then, do /save, and quit irssi.

And then restart irssi, and voila - it will autoconnect everywhere you configured it to.

If you'll have any problems, just consult [docs](http://irssi.org/documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

> sudo gedit ~/.irssi/config

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically `IDENTIFY` in Irssi from a password stored in your `~/.bashrc` file. Irssi allows the use of environment variables in its config file, (in much the same way that you would use them in any bash script).

First export your password.

**~/.bashrc**

```
export FREENODE_PASSWORD='your_password'
```

Then run `IDENTIFY` with the `autosendcmd` inside of `chatnets`. Make sure you add a wait period to the beginning of the command to make sure it runs after the server is ready.

**~/.irssi/config**

```
chatnets = {
  Freenode = {
    type = "IRC";
    nick = "your_nick";
    autosendcmd = "wait 2000; /msg NickServ IDENTIFY $FREENODE_PASSWORD";
  }
}
```

Comment: For anybody here thinking that you can use env variables elsewhere in the config: turns out, you cannot. This means you can't use them in sasl_password or other config settings in particular. [The functionality that handles these "expandos" _only_ runs for the autosendcmd and commands run when irssi is open.](https://github.com/irssi/irssi/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=eval_special_string&type=)